# Stop Update if value trying to be updated is different SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I would like to stop an update query if the value of a column trying to be updated is different than what it is trying to be updated to. I have this trigger:

```
create trigger dbo.NoUpdate
on HistoricalValues With Encryption
for update
as
   if update (value)
   begin
       rollback transaction
   end
```

But I would like to add something like this (pseudo code):

```
if update(value) and oldValue != newValue
   rollback transaction
```

Where `oldValue` is the value currently in the row and new value is the proposed value from the update statement.

This has to work with SQL Server 2014 Express at a minimum.

Comment: If you don't want people to `UPDATE` a specific column, wouldn't you be better off with a permissions based approach?

Comment: @Larnu permissions aren't an option because I have to assure that even a sa account could not modify the value. I already have a solution to making sure the trigger cannot be disabled, deleted or changed.

Comment: Why are people using the `sa` account at all for tasks other than to do sysadmin tasks?

Comment: @Larnu application can be installed on an existing sql cluster i do not control. therefore someone COULD use the sa account to do something nefarious. I just have to prevent a certain value from ever being updated. Simply blocking any update does not satisfy the requirement due to another part of the stack. That's why i need value comparison also.

Comment: So someone could use the `sa` account to disable to trigger...

Comment: @Larnu See second comment "I already have a solution to making sure the trigger cannot be disabled, deleted or changed."

Comment: *""I already have a solution to making sure the trigger cannot be disabled, deleted or changed."* That won't stop an `sa` that knows what they're doing. The `sa` can do **anything**.

Comment: Either way, I've given you solutions for either approach, and my recommendation. Neither, however will stop an `sa` if they *tried* for more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment *"If you don't want people to `UPDATE` a specific column, wouldn't you be better off with a permissions based approach?"*, personally I would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (id int IDENTITY,
                            GoodColumn varchar(10),
                            BadColumn varchar(10));
GO

CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON dbo.YourTable TO TestUser;
GO

DENY UPDATE ON dbo.YourTable(BadColumn) TO TestUser;
GO


INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (GoodColumn,
                           BadColumn)
VALUES('test123','example12'),
      ('test456','example34');
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';
GO
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET GoodColumn = 'Test789'
WHERE BadColumn = 'example34';
GO

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET BadColumn = 'Example56'
WHERE GoodColumn = 'test123';
GO

REVERT;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
GO
DROP USER TestUser;
```

If, for some reason, you *must* use a `TRIGGER`, you could do something like this, however, I still suggest the permissions approach:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.NoUpdateBad ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM Inserted i
                    JOIN deleted d ON i.id = d.id
               WHERE d.BadColumn != i.BadColumn
                  OR (d.BadColumn IS NULL AND i.BadColumn IS NOT NULL)
                  OR (d.BadColumn IS NOT NULL AND i.BadColumn IS NULL))
        THROW 51000, N'Cannot change the value of the column "BadColumn".',1;

GO

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET BadColumn = 'asdjk'
WHERE id = 2;
GO

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET BadColumn = NULL
WHERE id = 1;

GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

As I mention, however, neither of these will stop an `sa` account. `DENY` is ignored by `sysadmin` privileged accounts, and an `sa` would easily be able to disable to above trigger; even if you gave them a hurdle to jump first. it's much like thinking that turning `xp_cmdshell` well stop someone with access to an `sa` account. It doesn't, it's just a 1 second bump in the road to them, as they're just enable it.

Comment: but ... but ... OP already has a solution! Why can you not see this? :)